# How do I handle a like query using Mobility in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobility

The title says it all. The goal is to handle a simple search.

Trying to do this in my controller, which worked with Globalize:

```rb
query = "%#{query}%"
docs = Doc.i18n.where(category_id: category_ids)
docs = docs.where("title like ?", query)
```

Based on this model:

```rb
class Doc < ApplicationRecord
  extend Mobility
  translates :title, type: :string
end
```

The following error is the result:

`Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'title' in 'where clause'`

I've tried the following, which doesn't throw an error, but doesn't work either (it returns all Doc records):

```rb
docs = docs.where("title like #{query}", locale: :en)
```

And I've tried this, but it doesn't actually seem to query anything (it returns all Doc records):

```rb
docs.i18n do
  title.matches(query)
end
```

I can't find any documentation on how to handle querying with the `like` operator using Mobility. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The following error is the result:
```

If that worked in Globalize, it's only because the translations table has a column named `title`. Strings are not parsed by Mobility (or Globalize) so never expect that hand-crafted SQL will work with translated attributes.

```
Doc.i18n { title.matches(query) }
```

should work (it's in the Mobility readme). If not you've got something else going on in your model.

Comment: Yep, saw it in the readme, but didn't see anything about hand-crafted SQL not working. Thanks for the response.